# displaying an updated list of Items added to ListBox Immediately without navigating from and back to a page in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have a page in my windows phone 8.0 Silverlight app, the page displays list of comments from a web service. using MVVM, In the view model used by the commentspage, I have a delegate command that I bound to a button click to send a POST to the service after the user has typed text in a textbox. When I click the button, the operation is successful, but the ListBox don't display updated comment added, until, i leave the page and navigate back to the page.
The Collection is defined like this.

```
private ObservableCollection<Comment> commentList;
    public ObservableCollection<Comment> CommentList
    {
        get
        {
            return commentList;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.commentList, value);
        }
    }
```

The send button is bound to a Delegate command defined like this

```
private DelegateCommand userSubmitCommentCommand;
    public DelegateCommand UserSubmitCommentCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (userSubmitCommentCommand == null)
                userSubmitCommentCommand = new DelegateCommand(UserSubmitCommentCommandClick);
            return userSubmitCommentCommand;
        }
    }
```

UsersubmitCommentCommandClick here;

```
private async void UserSubmitCommentCommandClick()
    {


            try
            {
                if (BaseViewModel.HelperClass.IsInternet())
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Message))
                    {


                            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Constants.Comment_API);
                            webRequest.Method = "POST";
                            webRequest.UserAgent = "immtv.loveworldapis.com";
                            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                            webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestSubmitCommentStreamCallback), webRequest);


                        // UserCommentPopUpOpen = Visibility.Collapsed;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("First Enter Comment");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000);

                    MessageBoxResult msgResult = MessageBox.Show(Constants.NETWORK_ERROR, Constants.NETWORK_ERROR_TITLE, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

                    if (msgResult == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                    {
                        UserSubmitCommentCommandClick();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Application.Current.Terminate();
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                BaseViewModel.ShowErrorMessage();
            }


    }
```

GetRequestSubmitCommentStreamCallback here;

```
void GetRequestSubmitCommentStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        try
        {
            string requestBody = "";
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
            Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);

            requestBody = "email=" + BaseViewModel.UserEmailId + "&comment=" + Message + "&video_id=" + BaseViewModel.SelectedVideoID;

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);

            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            postStream.Close();

            webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseUserSubmitCommentStreamCallback), webRequest);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            BaseViewModel.ShowErrorMessage();
        }
    }
```

and the GetResponseUserSubmitCommentStreamCallback here;

```
void  GetResponseUserSubmitCommentStreamCallback(IAsyncResult calldatabackResult)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)calldatabackResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(calldatabackResult);
            using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                UserStatusData = JSONHelper.DeserializeFromJson<CeFlix.Entities.UserStatusData>(result);

            }
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                if (UserStatusData.status == "OK")
                {
                    //  this.GetCommentList();
                    this.Message = string.Empty;
                    MessageBox.Show("Comment Added Successfully");
                    CommentsPageViewModel commentsPageViewModel = CommentsPageViewModel.GetSingleInstance();
                    commentsPageViewModel.GetCommentList();

                }
            });

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                BaseViewModel.ShowErrorMessage();
            });
        }
    }
```

At the code behind of the CommentsPage, a page where users can view list of comment and also post comment, here is how I bound the view model to the page

```
public CommentsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.commentsPageViewModel = CommentsPageViewModel.GetSingleInstance();
        this.DataContext = commentsPageViewModel;
    }

    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        this.commentsPageViewModel = new CommentsPageViewModel();
        this.DataContext = commentsPageViewModel;


        await commentsPageViewModel.GetVideoDetail();
        await commentsPageViewModel.GetCommentList();

        if (BaseViewModel.IsUserLoggedIn != "true")
        {
            signInPopUp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

In XAML this is the ListBox to display list of comments

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbxComments" Margin="0,0,-12,0" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding CommentList,Mode=TwoWay}"
                 SelectionChanged="lbxComments_SelectionChanged"
                 >...
```

I set a break point in the code that says `commentsPageViewModel.GetCommentList();`
I saw that the comments list was really updated in the service, but the ListBox won't show the updated newly added comment unless one moves away from the page and navigates back. Pls what do I do, so that users see their comment on the page immediately without moving away. also I want the ListBox to refresh when users drag down the ListBox so that they can see if any other person added comment from another device.

Comment: Has the page datacontext bound to the viewmodel where you are updating the commentList? If not  the ListBox ItemSource will not know where to find the CommentList that can be bind.

Comment: Yes, the page's DataContext is bound to the ViewModel that gets the commentList, so in the delegate command that is bound to the button that the user uses to post comment, I call the GetComment() method again.

Comment: If there could be a way to refresh or reload the ListBox or page's content, without moving away from the page, please let me know

Comment: Jegan is telling you that you need to have something in your code that does something like CommentList.Add(Message).  CommentList is the collection that your ListBox is bound to - sending the message to the server does not magically add it to your local collection.

Comment: After sending the message to the server, I call the GetCommentList() method, and when I set a break point there to see what happens after I send a message, I saw that the CommentList is updated but the ListBox does not trigger a change, except I renavigate to the page